# How to use HtmlDocument's TryGetHtml

Tags: f#, f#-data

Say I have a a function

```
let GetDataFromWebsite (url:string) =
    let webpage = HtmlDocument.Load(url)
    let html = webpage.TryGetHtml
    html
```

(note that this will become a longer function once I work out how to use the `TryGetHtml` function)

This tells me that it has a return `string -> unit -> HtmlNode option`.  What is this exactly returning and how do I use it?  I have tried

```
match GetDataFromWebsite(@"...") with
| None -> "None"
| _ -> (fun a -> a.ToString())
|> printfn "%s"
```

but visual studio states that:

```
This expresion was expected to have type
  'unit -> FSharp.Data.HtmlNode option'
but here has type
  ''a option'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly there :)

[TryGetHtml](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/reference/fsharp-data-htmldocumentmodule.html) is a function, not a property, and you likely want to evaluate it instead of assigning it:

```
let GetDataFromWebsite (url:string) =
    let webpage = HtmlDocument.Load(url)
    let html = webpage.TryGetHtml() // note braces
    html
```

Now it returns `HtmlNode option` you can pattern match on:

```fs
match GetDataFromWebsite(@"...") with
| None -> "None"
| Some x -> x.ToString()
|> printfn "%s"
```

This should compile without errors.